# Recursively reorder dataframe columns for arbitrary number of dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wish to reorder the columns of a variable number of PySpark dataframes (they have the same columns but in a different order).
The dataframe which dictates the order is irrelevant as long as all dataframes end up having the same order as one another.
Below function works for 2 dataframes and my question is: how does this generalize for any number of dataframes (2, 3, etc.)?

```
def reorder_cols(df_1, df_2):
    """Reorder dataframe columns in df_1 based on order of columns in df_2."""
    return df_1.select(df_2.schema.names)
```

I have tried with `functools.reduce` and defining the function signature as `*dfs` but am unsure how to go from here:

```
from functools import reduce

def reorder_cols_r(*dfs):
    """Reorder dataframe columns recursively."""
    return reduce(DataFrame.select, dfs)
```

Some test data I am using:

```
# Test dataframes
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo1"), (2, "bar1")], ("a", "b"))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("foo2", 3), ("bar2", 4)], ("b", "a"))
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([(5, "foo3"), (6, "bar3")], ("a", "b"))
```

The function would then get called in this manner:

```
reorder_cols_r(*[df1, df2, df3])
```

Note: should work for any number of columns, as long as they are present in all dataframes. 2 columns are just used above for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for map:

```
def reorder_cols_r(dfs):
    return list(map(lambda x: x.select(dfs[0].columns), dfs))
```

which you can call with

```
new_dfs = reorder_cols_r([df1, df2, df3])
```

and the resulting dfs are:

```
>>> [x.show() for x in new_dfs]
+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  1|foo1|
|  2|bar1|
+---+----+

+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  3|foo2|
|  4|bar2|
+---+----+

+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  5|foo3|
|  6|bar3|
+---+----+
```